# c# capture microphone

Tags: c#

Can someone tell me how could I capture the microphone and send it over IP? Is there any example of how to capture and put into a buffer in order to send it on UDP socket to another computer and listen the song? I'm working in c#. THX. I would really apprecciate if there is someone who can give me an example:)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924178/real-time-audio-playback-from-mic-c/3934175#3934175

Comment: What are your requirements? Speech or music? Bandwidth? Latency?

Answer (score 1):

you can find some open source projects you could get inspired from: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Open+Source+VOIP+Software

if you just want to stream audio via UDP maybe you don't need a full implementation of the SIP stack but if you want to make a skype-clone you probably do.

Comment: The OP mentioned that they want to play a song down the wire.  VOIP wouldn't be suitable for this because it's optimised for the human vocal frequency range, which is far too limited for playing music.

Comment: Right, sorry I have not seen the word song in the initial post.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're transferring music and not speech I recommend Vorbis as codec and not Speex. There are some C# wrappers available. Vorbis has higher latency and bandwidth than Speex, but Speex only works well for speech and not for music.

Mine is available on github: https://github.com/CodesInChaos/Xiph
It also includes a wrapper to the noise suppression of the speex pre-processor. But I've never tried it on music.

Is there any reason why you want UDP? If latency isn't *very* important I'd just use TCP instead.

To get the audio you can use NAudio, or as I did the code from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Streaming_wave_audio.aspx